# Не могу разобраться с функциями в ООП

Tags: php, ооп

Есть такой код:

```
    <?php
include 'pest.php';
class Card
{
    public $token = '';
    public function GetToken()
    {
        $curlHandle = curl_init('https://vupsen.ru:9900/api/0/auth/access_token?user_id=test&user_secret=test');
        curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $execResult = curl_exec($curlHandle);
        $info = curl_getinfo($curlHandle);
        $resultOrder = json_decode($execResult, true);
        return $resultOrder; //Тут нужное мне значение.
    }
    public function GetOrgList()
    {
        $token = $this->GetToken(); // Тут ошибка
        $curlHandle = curl_init('https://vupsen.ru:9900/api/0/organization/list?access_token='.$token);
        curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $execResult = curl_exec($curlHandle);
        $info = curl_getinfo($curlHandle);
        $result = json_decode($execResult, true);
        $orgid = $result[6];
        return $orgid;
    }
}
?>
```

Простите, что глупый вопрос. Изучил все подобные ошибки, ничего найти не смог.

То есть мне нужно с функции GetToken получить токен и использовать его в функции GetOrgList в запросе. 
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А что за ошибка то?

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context in /home/v/vupsen/vupsen.beget.tech/public_html/iko/func.php:17

Comment: А можете добавить код там где вы используете этот класс?

Comment: Интеграцией этого класса буду заниматься не я. Я просто выполняю "отладку" используя например echo Card::GetOrgList().'<br>'. Дело в том, что я просто не понимаю как передать в ООП значение из одной функции в другую.

Comment: Добавьте static после видимости функции(public/private/protected) что бы функции были статичными и вызывались как Card::GetOrgList(), $this-> на self::

Comment: Они и вызывались у меня раньше, с этим все в порядке. Проблема в другом:

Comment: Мне нужно из первой функции просто передать переменную во вторую. Просто нужно чтобы  $resultOrder был в GetOrgList

Answer (score 1):

Так как вы вызываете метод статически(вот так `Card::GetOrgList()`), то и выходит ошибка которую вы описали. Потому что статические методы не могут использовать `$this`;
Создайте экземпляр класса и вызывайте метод:

```
$card = new Card();
$list = $card->GetOrgList()
```